# colgroupにborderが反映されない

Tags: html, css

背景色は適用できるのですが、borderが反映されません。

[MDNのborderのページ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/border) には適用対象はすべての要素となっているのですが、なぜなのでしょうか？

環境
Chrome (103)、Firefox (103)

HTML

```
<table>
  <caption>テーブルの練習</caption>
  <colgroup span="4"></colgroup>
  <colgroup>
    <col></col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>見出し1
      <th>見出し2
      <th>見出し3
      <th>見出し4
      <th>フラグ
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>データ1
      <td>データ2
      <td>データ3
      <td>データ4
      <td>no
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>データ1
      <td>データ2
      <td>データ3
      <td>データ4
      <td>yes
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

css

```
table{
  border-spacing:0;
  width:50%;
  text-align:center;
}
colgroup:nth-of-type(1){
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background-color:rgb(255 0 0 / 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

borderの指定要素をcolgroupではなく、tableを指定してみてはどうですか？